# Using EDN license instead of purchasing full ArcGIS licenses?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-server, license, edn

I am planning to start a business in Turkey and I need GIS software. At this moment, ArcGIS seems to be most convenient software option to me.

I'm wondering if I need the **EDN License** for the first time. Because when you try to buy ArcGIS for Desktop (with most of its extensions, with a price of $2,500.00 for each extension) and ArcGIS for Server, you confront a really huge budget.

But EDN License is annual. I'll have to pay $4000 for every year. It makes sense when you grow your business up. But at the starting point?

Comment: I'm not sure if this falls within the scope of the site, since it's both a legal as well as shopping question. Additionally, you are comparing Apples and Oranges. AFAIK, The EDN license only allows you to use the software for development purposes. Production use of the software is not allowed under the EDN.

Comment: So I cannot use ArcGIS software for commercial purposes with EDN License? I thought this kind of usage was included...

Comment: why not open-source options? why arcgis is so special in this case?

Comment: I'd like to try open source options. But we couldn't get over performance issues in big projects with big data.

Comment: Try get some help from Open source experts, a bit of consulting will cost you far less than the ArcGIS licenses, and will surely help you overcome the performance issues. Because there are lots of big data projects being done in OpenSource (e.g. OpenStreetMap).

Comment: @vestanbul: That is what I've read, and been told when I was working in the ESRI Support team. It might be different for your country. It's best to get it clarified with the ESRI Distributor in Turkey.

Comment: Actually, ESRI Distributor in Turkey is not really good at supporting. They don't return your e-mails or calls. That is why I have used this platform to ask.

Comment: @vestanbul: If your distributor is not responsive, how do you expect to buy the software, and get support from them? If they are providing such terrible support before you purchase the software, you should be weary of how they will act once they have your money. Maybe you need to rethink if selecting ESRI technology would be a good bet from a long term point of view.

Comment: Devdetta, I thought they are not responsive just because I am not a customer yet. There are so many customers of ESRI in Turkey. So the customers should have their support right?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because Licensing questions for commercial software should be made direct to the vendor, particularly where it involves interpretation of the license agreement

Answer (score 9):

I'm not a lawyer, but as per my understanding, you can use the EDN license, only for development & customization. You cannot use the software in production.

What this means is that one license allows one developer to develop customization and tools against the standard APIs. You cannot for example use the ArcGIS Desktop for Analyzing data or Creating maps. You cannot use the ArcGIS Server under this license for just publishing the service for commercial purposes.

The [New site](http://www.esri.com/software/arcgis/edn/what-you-get) mentions:

> EDN licenses are solely for the purposes of research, development, testing, and demonstration of your application. Each EDN subscription can only be used by a single authorized developer.

The [older site](http://edn.esri.com/index.cfm?fa=misc.program#item5) is much more explicit:

> - EDN software licenses are for the sole purposes of research and development only—internal development or development of government off-the-shelf (GOTS) or commercial off-the-shelf (COTS) products. EDN licenses may not be used for production or used by concurrent developers.
> - EDN does not include the right to any deployments, run times, or server technology for production or commercial uses.

This information is valid in the US, but since you are in Turkey, you should confirm this information by talking to the ESRI distributor in your country.

Additionally, as [Jens](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/82779/advice-on-arcgis-purchase-options/82784?noredirect=1#comment114119_82784) has mentioned in a comment below, EDN does not come with support. Support comes at an [additional price](http://www.esri.com/software/arcgis/edn/pricing) of $2000 (at least in the US)

Comment: this answer is very helpful. I appreciate your help. I should push the distributor to guide me about this.

Comment: +1. Additional "special feature" of EDN licenses: AFAIK a EDN license does NOT include support. You have to buy   support separately ([$ 2,000 in US](http://www.esri.com/software/arcgis/edn/pricing))